# Drill Up/Down using buttons

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

I am attempting to create some command buttons that would allow a user to drill down and up in a Power-pivot hierarchy. I have been able to generate the code that drills down when I reference a specific line on the sheet, but I have been unable to adjust it to drill down/p based on the line/cell the user has selected.

Is it possible to change `.PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(1)` to something like `.ActiveCell`?

My full code:

```
Sub DrillDown()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DrillDown ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Data].[Dive1].[ASSIGNEDTO]").PivotItems( _
        "[Data].[Dive1].[ASSIGNEDTO].&[Adjustment, MyDB]"), ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(1)
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Notify
    Msg = "Unable to Drill Down any further"
    Style = vbError
    Title = "Drll Down Error"
    Notify = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)


End Sub

Sub DrillUp()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DrillUp ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Data].[Dive1].[ClientID]").PivotItems( _
        "[Data].[Dive1].[ASSIGNEDTO].&[Adjustment, MYDB].&[QMMX123]"), _
        ActiveCell.Select
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Dim Msg, Style, Title, Notify
    Msg = "Unable to Up any further"
    Style = vbError
    Title = "Drill Up Error"
    Notify = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)


End Sub
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use the built-in drill down and drill up buttons in the pivot table Analyze ribbon menu?

Comment: @greggyb We are trying to create a module that would lock out all other menus when a user opens the Excel file. Given that the user base for this product is in experienced with a lot of the newer features, the alternative would be for us to go around and train every user on how to drill up and down. If we are successful at making these buttons, we will be able to lock all other areas down and give the user only the ability to use the features we provided.

Comment: Have you recorded macros of using the drill up/down menu buttons, because they do exactly what you want - you should be able to get what you need from the behavior of those buttons and modify minimally. They are cell-selection-sensitive

Comment: @greggyb that is actually how I was able to discover the above logic; I used the record feature to identify how the drill up/down features were referenced. Unfortunately as you said, the record feature is cell selection sensitive, which is why I was hoping there is a way to specify the selection prior to execution.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Unfortunately VBA is not where I spend most of my play-time. Can you just do some arithmetic on the row number of the active cell, since you know where in the sheet PivotLines(1) is - it's anchored at the top of the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dedicating some time to this and getting some ideas from some friends, I was able to write the code that allows you to create custom buttons that will Drill Down, Drill Up and Drill to Top of your pivot hierarchy.

I am by no means an expert in VBA and am open to suggestions on ways to improve this. I found this code to be extremely useful for the product I was making, so I thought I would share in an effort to give something back to the community.

I designed code to be as simple as possible and to be able to reuse the code with minimal modifications; therefore I use a naming prefix of "Lvl" and numbered the levels 1-4 (however I coded it so that you could specify your own custom prefix as well). 
Given that you are able to rename your fields in the actual pivot table without affecting the back end, the hierarchy prefix will not cause any customization issues.

Last note: there are a few sections that need user input of your prefixes, table names, etc. and are marked with "User entry needed". Also, this was developed using the AdventureWorks SQL sample database (excel connected to SQL via power query and pulled the data into the Excel data model).

Please feel free to ask if you have any questions and I hope this helps!

```
Sub DrillDown()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'This code was developed by stackoverflow user CITYINBETWEEN and was posted on the stackoverflow 
'forums for everyone to use free of charge and is not to be sold to others.   
'
' Drill Down Macro
'
    Dim HrchyPreFix, HrchyLstLvl, MyCurrLocation, MyPivTblName, MyDrillTo
    '---------- User Entry Needed ----------'
    ' prefix used for hierarchy levels
    HrchyPreFix = "Lvl"
    ' set hierarchy last drill down level
    HrchyLstLvl = "4"
    '---------- End of User Entry ----------'

    ' set pivot table name of active cell
    MyPivTblName = ActiveCell.PivotTable
    ' set pivot field selected of active cell
    MyCurrLocation = ActiveCell.PivotCell.PivotField
    ' set what hierarchy lvl to drill down to
    MyDrillTo = ActiveCell.PivotCell.PivotItem

    ' find current hierarchy lvl of active cell. if at the last lvl, if statement goes to BottomOfDrillDownHandler
    HrchyCurrLvl = (Right(Left(Mid(ActiveCell.PivotField, InStr(1, ActiveCell.PivotField, HrchyPreFix)), 4), 1))
    ' If at last hierarchy lvl, go to BottomOfDrillDownHandler
    If HrchyCurrLvl = HrchyLstLvl Then
        GoTo BottomOfDrillDownHandler
    End If

    ' drill down code
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(MyPivTblName).DrillDown ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        MyPivTblName).PivotFields(MyCurrLocation).PivotItems(MyDrillTo), _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(MyPivTblName).PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(1)
    Exit Sub

' Error handler for when you cannot drill down any further
BottomOfDrillDownHandler:
    Dim ErrMsg1, ErrTitle1
    ErrMsg1 = "Unable to Drill Down any further as you're at the bottom of the Drill Down"
    ErrTitle1 = "Drill Down Error"
    MsgBox ErrMsg1, , ErrTitle1
    Exit Sub

' general error handler
ErrorHandler:
    Dim ErrMsg2, ErrTitle2, ErrMsg3, ErrTitle3
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        ErrMsg2 = "Please select a drillable item"
        ErrTitle2 = "Drill Down Error"
        MsgBox ErrMsg2, , ErrTitle2
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ErrMsg3 = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
            & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        ErrTitle3 = "Error"
    MsgBox ErrMsg3, , ErrTitle3, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub DrillUp()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'This code was developed by stackoverflow user CITYINBETWEEN and was posted on the stackoverflow 
'forums for everyone to use free of charge and is not to be sold to others.   
'
' Drill Up 1 level Macro
'
    Dim PwrPivTblNm, HrchyNm, HrchyPreFix, HrchyTopLvl, MyCurrLocation, MyPivTblName, MyDrillTo, MyCurrLvl, HrchyPrevLvl As Integer

    '---------- User Entry Needed ----------'
    ' Name of table in powerpivot where the hierarchy exists
    PwrPivTblNm = "vEmployeeDepartment"
    ' name given to hierarchy in powerpivot
    HrchyNm = "Hierarchy1"
    ' prefix used for hierarchy levels
    HrchyPreFix = "Lvl"
    ' set top hierarchy level
    HrchyTopLvl = "1"
    '---------- End of User Entry ----------'

    ' set pivot table name of active cell
    MyPivTblName = ActiveCell.PivotTable
    ' set pivot field selected of active cell
    MyCurrLocation = ActiveCell.PivotCell.PivotField
    ' set from what hierarchy lvl to drill up from
    MyDrillUpFrom = ActiveCell.PivotCell.PivotItem
    ' find prev. hierarchy lvl of active cell
    HrchyPrevLvl = (Right(Left(Mid(ActiveCell.PivotField, InStr(1, ActiveCell.PivotField, HrchyPreFix)), 4), 1) - 1)

    ' find current hierarchy lvl of active cell. if at the top lvl, if statement goes to TopOfDrillUpHandler
    HrchyCurrLvl = (Right(Left(Mid(ActiveCell.PivotField, InStr(1, ActiveCell.PivotField, HrchyPreFix)), 4), 1))
    ' If at last hierarchy lvl, go to TopOfDrillUpHandler
    If HrchyCurrLvl = HrchyTopLvl Then
        GoTo TopOfDrillUpHandler
    End If

    ' set hierarchy level to drill up to
    HrchyLvlDrillTo = "[" & PwrPivTblNm & "].[" & HrchyNm & "].[" & _
                    Mid(ActiveCell.PivotField, InStr(1, ActiveCell.PivotField, HrchyPreFix), 3) & HrchyPrevLvl _
                    & "]"

    ' drill up code
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(MyPivTblName).DrillUp ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        MyPivTblName).PivotFields(MyCurrLocation).PivotItems(MyDrillUpFrom), _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(MyPivTblName).PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(1), HrchyLvlDrillTo
    Exit Sub

' Error handler for when you cannot drill up any further
TopOfDrillUpHandler:
    Dim ErrMsg1, ErrTitle1
    ErrMsg1 = "Unable to Drill Up any further as you're at the top of the Drill Up"
    ErrTitle1 = "Drill Up Error"
    MsgBox ErrMsg1, , ErrTitle1
    Exit Sub

' General Error handler
ErrorHandler:
    Dim ErrMsg2, ErrTitle2, ErrMsg3, ErrTitle3
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        ErrMsg2 = "Please select a drillable item"
        ErrTitle2 = "Drill Up Error"
        MsgBox ErrMsg2, , ErrTitle2
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ErrMsg3 = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
            & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        ErrTitle3 = "Error"
    MsgBox ErrMsg3, , ErrTitle3, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub


'--------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub DrillToTop()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
'This code was developed by stackoverflow user CITYINBETWEEN and was posted on the stackoverflow 
'forums for everyone to use free of charge and is not to be sold to others.   
'
' Dill To Top Macro Macro
'
    Dim PwrPivTblNm, HrchyNm, HrchyPreFix, HrchyTopLvl, MyCurrLocation, MyPivTblName, MyDrillTo

    '---------- User Entry Needed ----------'
    ' Name of table in powerpivot where the hierarchy exists
    PwrPivTblNm = "vEmployeeDepartment"
    ' name given to hierarchy in powerpivot
    HrchyNm = "Hierarchy1"
    ' prefix used for hierarchy levels
    HrchyPreFix = "Lvl"
    ' set top hierarchy level
    HrchyTopLvl = "1"
    '---------- End of User Entry ----------'

    ' set pivot table name of active cell
    MyPivTblName = ActiveCell.PivotTable
    ' set pivot field selected of active cell
    MyCurrLocation = ActiveCell.PivotCell.PivotField
    ' set from what hierarchy lvl to drill up from
    MyDrillUpFrom = ActiveCell.PivotCell.PivotItem

    ' find prev. hierarchy lvl of active cell. if already at top lvl, if statement goes to AlreadyAtTopHandler
    HrchyPrevLvl = (Right(Left(Mid(ActiveCell.PivotField, InStr(1, ActiveCell.PivotField, "Lvl")), 4), 1) - 1)
    ' If at hierarchy lvl 1, go to TopOfDrillUpHandler
    If HrchyPrevLvl = "0" Then
        GoTo AlreadyAtTopHandler
    End If

    ' set top hierarchy level to drill up to
    HrchyLvlDrillTo = "[" & PwrPivTblNm & "].[" & HrchyNm & "].[" & _
                    Mid(ActiveCell.PivotField, InStr(1, ActiveCell.PivotField, HrchyPreFix), 3) & HrchyTopLvl _
                    & "]"

    ' drill to top code
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(MyPivTblName).DrillUp ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        MyPivTblName).PivotFields(MyCurrLocation).PivotItems(MyDrillUpFrom), _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(MyPivTblName).PivotRowAxis.PivotLines(1), _
        HrchyLvlDrillTo
    Exit Sub

' Error handler for when user is already at the top level
AlreadyAtTopHandler:
    Dim ErrMsg1, ErrTitle1
    ErrMsg1 = "Unable to Drill to Top as you're already at the top level"
    ErrTitle1 = "Drill to Top Error"
    MsgBox ErrMsg1, , ErrTitle1
    Exit Sub

' General Error handler
ErrorHandler:
    Dim ErrMsg2, ErrTitle2, ErrMsg3, ErrTitle3
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        ErrMsg2 = "Please select a drillable item"
        ErrTitle2 = "Drill to Top Error"
        MsgBox ErrMsg2, , ErrTitle2
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ErrMsg3 = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
            & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        ErrTitle3 = "Error"
    MsgBox ErrMsg3, , ErrTitle3, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice.  Can it be done using DAX instead so it would work with Power BI?

Comment: @Lee if you are going to be hosting this on a power pivot enabled library, you can use the standard hierarchy drilling methods. That being said, I do not think you would be able to create custom functions using dax alone.

Comment: This is possible in Power BI, I've got it working nicely.  Hope to follow up with more info but others should not be discouraged.

Comment: @Lee that is awesome; you should post your solution if there are no posts explaining it.